# JBoss Hibernate: Could not load requested class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate, jboss

I have an instalation of JBoss that was working with postgresql...
I'm tring to change to mySQL.

I've downloaded mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar and put it into JBOSS_HOME/module/com/mysql/main, created the module.xml and changed my standalone.xml.

But whem I try start the server i got the folloing stacktrace:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."myapp.war#myapp": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."myapp.war#myapp": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: myapp] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: myapp] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver could not be loaded
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1825)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1783)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:318)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:148)
    ... 22 more
```

Can someone help?

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="myapp">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <!-- Annotated entity classes -->
        <class>br.com.programadoremjava.ginga.test.myapp.entity.MyClassA</class>
        <class>br.com.programadoremjava.ginga.test.myapp.entity.MyClassB</class>

        <properties>
            <!-- DADOS CONEXAO -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="application" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="application" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp" />

            <!-- CONFIGURACAO -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

My standalone.xml datasource configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/myapp-ds" pool-name="test" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp</connection-url>
            <driver>com.mysql</driver>
            <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
                <prefill>true</prefill>
                <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
            </pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>application</user-name>
                <password>application</password>
            </security>
            <statement>
                <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
            </statement>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
                <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

My JBOSS_HOME/module/com/mysql/main/module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to refer to the as datasource in persistence.xml
`<jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/myapp-ds</jta-data-source>` and remove all hibernate.connection.* properties. The connection is managed by the application server in that scenario you do not need it to redefine it in hibernate.